# i want to pass props through but still getting error

Tags: reactjs

hello guys i have component of login i want to pass its values in home components but i still getting error like that

```
TypeError: this.props.come is not a function
this.props.come(this.state.id);
```

this is my login component

```
this.login=this.login.bind(this);

login(e)
{e.preventDefault();
if(this.state.id===''&& this.state.name===''&&this.state.gender==='')
{
    alert('fill ');

}
else{

}

if(this.state.id && this.state.name && this.state.gender)
    {
        this.props.come(this.state.id,this.state.name,this.state.gender);
    }
    else{
        console.log('nothing');
    }
```

and this is my home component where i am receving props

```
this.comingfromform=this.coming.bind(this);

coming(id,name,gender)
{
this.setState({yourid:id,yourname:name,yourgender:gender});
console.log('hey r u come ?');
}
<Route  path='/login' component={Login} come={this.coming.bind(this)}/>
          <Route  path='/join' component={Join}/>
```

i have just add the code of bind function i construtor onclick funtion from where props will pass and same as for home component... if u guys have any idea please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation about React-Router `Route` `render`:
[render: func](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

```
<Route path="somepath" render={() => <Login come={...} />} />
```

Comment: thanks alot :) May GOD bless you with alots of happiness :) may You Get Married with your Lover :P